# Help with my proof that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+e^{-x})^{x^2}=1$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

$
(1+e^{-x})^{x^2} = 
\Big(\big(1+e^{-x}\big)^{e^{x}}\Big)^{\frac{x^2}{e^x}}
$
Now I want to say, we know that $f(x)=(1+1/x)^x\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}e$, so we look at $e^x \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\infty$ and by Heine we get $f(e^x)\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}e$. But how do I denote "$e^x$ is a sequence real numbers" in terms of
$x_n=e^n$ when $n\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: There is something wrong in the title.

Comment: Your title is $\lim_{x\to\infty}(x+e^{-1})^{x^2}=1$, however, that would tend to $\infty$, not $1$.

Comment: And why is that? $x^2/e^x \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}0$

Comment: $\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(x+\frac{1}{e}\right)^{x^2} > \lim_{x \to \infty}(x^x) = +\infty$

Comment: my title was misleading but you could read that I didn't mean (x+...) but to (1+...)

Comment: I see, however, it still tends to $\infty$, because $|1+\frac{1}{e}| > 1$. So if we start raising that to a positive power ($x^2$), then we'll just get a larger and larger positive number, so:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{e}\right)^{x^2} = +\infty$$

Comment: Read the title again please...

Comment: don't downvote just because there is a mistake - point it out and the OP will fix it. -2 is unacceptable just for that. I've just upvoted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following interpretation of the question. Define $f(x)=(1+\frac 1 x)^x$. You seem to know that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = e$ and you want to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(e^x) = e$ using: for every sequence $x_n\to\infty$ one has $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = e$.

Your problem is now: what sequence should I choose to  prove the claim with $f(e^x)$?

One can do it with sequences, but then one needs to do it in two steps. Let $y_n\to\infty$ be an arbitrary sequence. Choose $x_n = e^{y_n}$ and notice that it also tends to infinity as $n\to\infty$. One has $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)=e$ , or in other words: $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(e^{y_n}) = e$. Since $y_n$ was arbitrary we have proven that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(e^x) = e$.

Comment: Finally an answer to my question. thank you.

Comment: @MorHaham Glad that I could help!

Comment: Btw, you wrote "One can do it with sequences, but then you need to do it in two steps". Is there another way to prove it?

Comment: @MorHaham yes using the definition of limit.

Comment: Of curse..you mean the definition by Cauchy. I just understood from your words there is a shorter way than with sequences.

Comment: @MorHaham no no I didn't mean that. This is pretty short.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we have that

$$\large{\left(1+\frac1{e^{x}}\right)^{x^2}=\left[\left(1+\frac1{e^{x}}\right)^{e^x}\right]^\frac{x^2}{e^x}}\to e^0=1$$

indeed since eventually $e^x>x^3$ we have

$$\frac{x^2}{e^x}<\frac{x^2}{x^3}=\frac1x\to 0$$

Comment: You didn't read my post...

Comment: @MorHaham I read but maybe I didn't understood which wat you are following to prove it.

Comment: the question is at the bottom of the post. My question is not how do I prove it or what is the limit, but how do I denote the sequence e^x...

Comment: @MorHaham Your start is good and from the fact that $x^2/e^x \to 0$ we can conclude.

Comment: I read your post and don't have a clue what you want. What does Heine have to do with anything?

Comment: @stevengregory $e^x$ is a sequence tends to infinity. So we can use the limit definition of Heine to put $x=e^x$ in the function $f(x) = (1+1/x)^x$

Comment: $e^x$ is not a sequence. $e^{x_n}$ and $e^{nx}$ are sequences but you didn't say that. I see that someone figured out what you were asking  and gave you a great answer. But he answered what you wanted to ask, not what you asked.

Comment: @stevengregory I asked how can I denote $e^x$ as a real numbers sequence. It is clear that I couldn't write it as a sequence because that was the question...